# SELECT * FROM Table WHERE col has at least 3 identical

Tags: mysql

I need to a MySQL query that returns the results of a table where the elements of a specific column are identical in at least 'n' records.

example pseudocode:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE col has at least 3 identical
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table where col in (
    select col from table group by col having count(*) > 3
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT col, COUNT(*) AS total FROM tbl GROUP BY col HAVING total >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table a
inner join (
    select col,n=count(*)
      from table
     group by col
    having count(*) >= 3 ) as b     
on (a.col=b.col)
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql allows you to write something like the following:

```
select *
from table
group by col
having count(*) >= 3
```

other dbmss force you to specify all columns explicitly and use `MAX` or `MIN` on them

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TableName t WHERE 2 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName p WHERE p.col = t.col)
```